# Trouble with change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 basis $U ,V$ in $R^3$ and $P$ the matrix of change of coordinates from $U->V$

$P,V$ are given and I need to find $U$

$v_1=(-2, 2, 3)$
$v_2=(-8, 5, 2)$
$v_3=(-7,2,6)$

$$ P=
 \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -1 \\
        -3 & -5 & 0 \\
        4 & 6 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What I did was:
$$ V = P\dot{}U$$
$$ U = P^{-1}\dot{}V$$

Then I compute $U$ and when I try to multiply P by U to get V the result is not V.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the details?

Comment: How can you possibly expect us to tell **you** what you did wrong  when you don't tell **us** what you did?  You say you found $U^{-1}$.  How did you do that and what did you get for $U^{-1}$.

Comment: I just asked why is my logic flawed I said that I computed U by that formula (did all the calculations correct) and when I tried to test if my result is correct by multiplying P by U the result wasn't V